# Trouble Integrating Locomotive Scroll and GSAP ScrollTrigger

Tags: gsap, smooth-scrolling, scrolltrigger

The issue I encountered is an unnecessary gap between the menu and hero content sections. This gap is not a result of my coding efforts. Additionally, the website's scrolling behavior is not smooth. Upon scrolling, you may notice that the scrollbar disappears unexpectedly. Although I initially applied custom CSS to the scrollbar, I removed it in an attempt to resolve the issue. It appears that the code I borrowed from CodePen includes a custom scrollbar implemented by Locomotive Scroll, but it does not function as intended.

Locomotive Scroll in isolation and found it to work seamlessly. Moreover, disabling Locomotive Scroll altogether resolved both the unnecessary gap and scrolling problems. However, I am keen on retaining Locomotive Scroll for its smooth scrolling capabilities.

My hypothesis is that the integration of both libraries is causing conflicts or overlapping functionalities.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you are asking about. Otherwise, it's impossible for us to answer your question. Here are StackOverflow's guidelines on formatting code in questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example